# Why can't I get my images to appear in table cells/nodes.. maybe I can get some closure?

Tags: javascript, image, loops, closures

I want to add a new image in each cell of the new table and give it the same source as the old table, and then make it clickable. Firstly, I did this:

```
function showData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(name) !== null) {
    var showme = localStorage.getItem(name);
    alert("I got the table");
    var newTable = document.createElement('table');
    newTable.innerHTML = showme;
    newTable.id = "newTable";

    newNumRows = newTable.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
    newNumCells = newTable.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
    newNumCols = newNumCells / newNumRows;
    alert(newNumRows);
    alert(newNumCells);
    alert(newNumCols);

    var newImages = newTable.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < newImages.length; i += 1) {
      var picSource = newImages[i]['src'];
      console.log(picSource);
    }

    function addNewImage(newNumCols) {
      var newImg = new Image();
      newImg.src = picSource;
      col.appendChild(newImg);
      newImg.onclick = function() {
        alert("WOW");
      };
    }

    for (r = 0; r < newNumRows; r++) {
      row = newTable.insertRow(-1);

      for (c = 0; c < newNumCols; c++) {
        col = row.insertCell(-1);
        addNewImage(newNumCols);
      }
    }

    var showIt = document.getElementById('holdTable');
    showIt.appendChild(newTable);
  }
}
```

This works to a certain extent, but, unfortunately, only the last image was displaying. So, I did a bit of looking around and I think it has to do with closure (apologies for any duplication), but it's a concept I am really struggling to understand. So then I tried this:

```
function showData() {
  if (localStorage.getItem(name) !== null) {
    hideTaskForm();
    var showme = localStorage.getItem(name);
    var oldTable = document.createElement('table');
    oldTable.innerHTML = showme;
    newTable = document.createElement('table');
    newTable.id = "newTable";
    var i, r, c, j;

    newNumRows = oldTable.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
    newNumCells = oldTable.getElementsByTagName('td').length;
    newNumCols = newNumCells / newNumRows;
    var newTableCells = newTable.getElementsByTagName('td');
    var getImages = oldTable.getElementsByTagName('img');

    for (r = 0; r < newNumRows; r++) {
      row = newTable.insertRow(-1);

      for (c = 0; c < newNumCols; c++) {
        makeNodes = row.insertCell(-1);
      }
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < newTableCells.length; j++) {
      var theNodeImage = document.createElement("img");
      newTableCells[j].appendChild(theNodeImage);
      alert(newTableCells[j].innerHTML); //This gives me img tags
    }

    for (i = 0; i < getImages.length; i += 1) {
      var oldSource = getImages[i]['src']; //gets the src of the images from the saved table
      console.log(oldSource);
      //alert(oldSource);//successfully alerts the image paths
      var newPic = new Image(); //creates a new image

      (function(newPic, oldSource) {
        newPic.src = oldSource;
        alert(newPic.src); //gives the same image paths
        newTable.getElementsByTagName('img').src = newPic.src; //This doesn't work - table is blank???
      })(newPic, oldSource);
    }

    var showIt = document.getElementById('holdTable');
    showIt.appendChild(newTable);
  }
}
```

Now, this doesn't throw any errors. However, nor does it fill the table. It does give me the source and I think I have created the new image objects to attach to the img tags in the newTableCells, but the table is showing up blank. I don't know where I am going wrong. All help really welcome.

Note: Even as a hobbyist, even I know there are probably tons of more efficient ways to do this, but I purposely did it this way to try and help me understand the logic of each step I was taking.

Comment: You should summarize your issues in few lines. You'll get hardly someone across actual app code. And you should try to ask about what you think is the issue even if your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Hi Matias, I thought it important for the problem I am having that I show the full function. However, your point is noted. As regards the problem, I think, from reading other questions, in the first code block the new Image(); is overwritten in each iteration of the loop and thus the last image is given. From this I saw that closure may be the issue. The loop where I create the new images is the problem. I just don't know how to implement it.. although I think I am close. If there are parts of the question you feel aren't relevant I will gladly edit.

Comment: @lnkers I try to check what's going on, but it would be easier with some runnable snippet

Comment: There is no closure of any significance in the first example. In `localStorage.getItem(name)` where is *name* initialised? `newTable.innerHTML = showme;` will fail in IE, it does not support setting the innerHTML property of tables (or any table element descendant other than cells).

Comment: @Matias Thanks I can try put together a snippet later - bit short of time right now.

Comment: @RobG Name is the key of the table in localStorage - it is earlier attached to the user id thus each table is connected to unique user. So if closure is not the issue how do I overcome the rewriting of the new Image() in the loop?

Comment: @Inkers Ok, sometimes reducing a case you get the solution yourself! :D But I'll check SO in some hours to see if you got that snippet here

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have:

```
var newImages = newTable.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i = 0; i < newImages.length; i += 1) {
  var picSource = newImages[i]['src'];
  console.log(picSource);
}
```

At the end of this, *picSource* has the value of the last image's *src* attribute. Then there is:

```
function addNewImage(newNumCols) {
  var newImg = new Image();
  newImg.src = picSource;
  col.appendChild(newImg);
  newImg.onclick = function() {
    alert("WOW");
  };
}
```

A value is passed to *newNumCols* but not used in the function. The value of *picSource* comes from the outer execution context and is not changed, so it's still the last image src from the previous for loop.

```
for (r = 0; r < newNumRows; r++) {
  row = newTable.insertRow(-1);

  for (c = 0; c < newNumCols; c++) {
    col = row.insertCell(-1);
    addNewImage(newNumCols);
  }
}
```

This loop just keeps calling *addNewImage* with a single parameter that isn't used in the function, so you get the same image over and over.

For the record, the *addNewImage* function does have a closure to *picSource*, but it also has a closure to all the variables of the outer execution contexts. This isn't the issue, though it perhaps masks the fact that you aren't setting a value for *picSource* on each call, so you get the left over value from the previous section of code.

You haven't provided any indication of the content of *showme*, so it's impossible to determine if this approach will work at all.

#### Note

Where you have:

```
var showme = localStorage.getItem(name);
alert("I got the table");
var newTable = document.createElement('table');
newTable.innerHTML = showme;
newTable.id = "newTable";
```

IE does not support setting the innerHTML property of table elements, though you can create an entire table as the innerHTML of some other element and set the innerHTML of a cell (tr, th). If you want to use this approach, consider:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<table id="newTable">' + showme + '<\/table>';
var newTable = div.firstChild;
```

Comment: Thanks RobG. I have tried to implement your suggestions and I now have four images showing in the new table at the end of the loop. I am still struggling to assign the source to those images. From reading your answer it seems that I am not getting and storing the image paths properly in the first place (as per the first piece of code in your answer)?