# How do I loop over images in table, get the src of ALL images and apply to new images in new table?

Tags: javascript, image, loops

I am looping through the images in a table, trying to get the source and then applying that src to a new image in a different table. I have managed to create new image objects in the new table cells (tested) but for some reason all I can get is the last image to display. Well, actually I know this is because the loop writes over the variable each time and it has the last value when it is applied, but I don't know how to get them all. Here is the relevant code. If you need more just holler or see [Why can't I get my images to appear in table cells/nodes.. maybe I can get some closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922814/why-cant-i-get-my-images-to-appear-in-table-cells-nodes-maybe-i-can-get-some) Thanks for your help.

```
newImages = newTable.getElementsByTagName('img');

for(var i = 0; i < newImages.length; i += 1) {
    var picSource = newImages[i]['src'];
    console.log(picSource);//This logs the path to the four different images
    var newImg = new Image();//creates a new image for each
    newImg.src = picSource;//gives each image src?? Just gives the last image
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you might go about this, either creating new *img* elements and copying over the *src* property, or just clone the element. For example, if you have the following table:

```
<table id="t0">
 <tr><td><img src="a.png">
 <tr><td><img src="b.png">
 <tr><td><img src="c.png">
</table>
```

You can get all the images in the document using *document.images*, but you want just the ones in the table so you can do:

```
var images = document.getElementById('t0').getElementsByTagName('img')
```

which is a live collection (it will be updated automatically if you add or remove images from the table), or using a selector:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('#t0 img')
```

which is a static collection that stays the same no matter what you do to the table. The first method is supported in all browsers in use, but most will also support the selector version.

To make another table with the same images by copying the *src* property, you could do:

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var row, cell, img;

for (var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++) {  
  row = table.insertRow(-1);
  cell = row.insertCell(-1);

  // create new image and append to cell
  img = new Image();
  img.src = images[i].src;
  cell.appendChild(img);
}
```

Using the clone method, the last 3 lines can be replaced with:

```
  cell.appendChild(images[i].cloneNode(false));
```

Finally, add the new table to the document:

```
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: Hey RobG, Thanks a lot. I will give it a go. I am slow at working through so may not be tonight. This looks irritatingly logical, clear and concise btw!!

Comment: Works a charm - thanks so much. I am always amazed at how complicated I can make these things in my head.

Comment: Cool, just remember that if using *getElementsByTagName* the collection is live, so if you add images to the same table they will be added to the collection as you go. In that case, setting *iLen* is very important to limit the loop but you'll still have issues if you insert new images at the start of the table. Consider converting the *images* collection to a static array and work with that (there are lots of *toArray* examples around).